# how to compute lagged investment in r

Tags: r, transform, lag

I have created `df1`

```
year gvkey  capex   ppent
2004  1004 13.033 139.137
2005  1004 16.296 213.380
2006  1004 29.891 260.167
2007  1004 30.334 310.393
2008  1004 27.535 245.586
2009  1004 28.855 334.430
...
```

I have created `df2`

```
year gvkey    ROA
2005  1004 0.02796478
2006  1004 0.04665171
2007  1004 0.05976127
2008  1004 0.06255035
2009  1004 0.03549220
2005  1013 0.06882688
...
```

I wan to create `df3`

```
year gvkey    ROA               lag_investment
2005  1004 0.02796478  capex from 2004 / ppent from 2004
2006  1004 0.04665171  capex from 2005 / ppent from 2005
2007  1004 0.05976127  capex from 2006 / ppent from 2006
2008  1004 0.06255035  capex from 2007 / ppent from 2007
2009  1004 0.03549220  capex from 2008 / ppent from 2008
2005  1013 0.06882688  capex from 2004 / ppent from 2004
...
```

I have over 2,000 firms years. `gvkey = firm id`

**What I basically want to do is the following:**

1) compute the investment for the previous year from `df1`

2) create a column called "lag_investment" in `df2`

2) insert the value from step 1) in the current year row in `df2`

**Additional question:**

How would the code look like if I want to do the following?

I have created   `df1`

```
  year gvkey        ROA   ppent  capex
1 2004  1004 0.01320911 139.137 13.033
2 2005  1004 0.03005708 213.380 16.296
3 2006  1004 0.05014214 260.167 29.891
4 2007  1004 0.06423255 310.393 30.334
5 2008  1004 0.06723031 245.586 27.535
6 2009  1004 0.03814769 334.430 28.855
...
```

I want to add a variable to `df1`

```
  year gvkey        ROA   ppent  capex         lag_investment
1 2004  1004 0.01320911 139.137 13.033
2 2005  1004 0.03005708 213.380 16.296  capex from 2004 / ppent from 2004
3 2006  1004 0.05014214 260.167 29.891  capex from 2005 / ppent from 2005
4 2007  1004 0.06423255 310.393 30.334  capex from 2006 / ppent from 2006
5 2008  1004 0.06723031 245.586 27.535  capex from 2007 / ppent from 2007
6 2009  1004 0.03814769 334.430 28.855  capex from 2008 / ppent from 2008
...
```

I want to calculate the lag_investment for all years except 2004.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lag_investment :=Reduce(`/`, shift(.SD)), .SDcols = c("capex", "ppent")]
df1
#   year gvkey        ROA   ppent  capex lag_investment
#1: 2004  1004 0.01320911 139.137 13.033             NA
#2: 2005  1004 0.03005708 213.380 16.296     0.09367027
#3: 2006  1004 0.05014214 260.167 29.891     0.07637079
#4: 2007  1004 0.06423255 310.393 30.334     0.11489159
#5: 2008  1004 0.06723031 245.586 27.535     0.09772772
#6: 2009  1004 0.03814769 334.430 28.855     0.11211958
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df1$lag_investment <- with(df1, c(NA, head(capex, -1)/head(ppent, -1)))
```

Or it can be written as

```
df1$lag_investment <- with(df1, c(NA, capex[-nrow(df1)]/ppent[-nrow(df1)]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(year = 2004:2009, gvkey = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L), ROA = c(0.01320911, 0.03005708, 0.05014214, 
0.06423255, 0.06723031, 0.03814769), ppent = c(139.137, 213.38, 
260.167, 310.393, 245.586, 334.43), capex = c(13.033, 16.296, 
29.891, 30.334, 27.535, 28.855)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use `lag` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(lag_investment = lag(capex)/lag(ppent))

#  year gvkey    ROA ppent capex lag_investment
#1 2004  1004 0.0132   139  13.0             NA
#2 2005  1004 0.0301   213  16.3         0.0937
#3 2006  1004 0.0501   260  29.9         0.0764
#4 2007  1004 0.0642   310  30.3         0.1149
#5 2008  1004 0.0672   246  27.5         0.0977
#6 2009  1004 0.0381   334  28.9         0.1121
```

If the dataframe is not ordered, use `arrange` first to order it by years.

```
df1 %>% arrange(year) %>% mutate(lag_investment = lag(capex)/lag(ppent))
```

---

Or `shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lag_investment := shift(capex)/shift(ppent)]
```